# Reading multiple ascii files and generate 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have 18 ascii files with a name (AA01, AA02, AA03...AA18) each one has 5220 row and 9 column. I am trying to import and read this files and save data in 3D matrix with dimensions (5220 x 9 x 18)

I used below code but it is not getting through

```
Folder = 'D:\My_Files';
Pattern = fullfile(Folder, '*.*'); 
Files = dir(Pattern);
for k = 1 : length(Files)
    baseFileName = Files(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(Folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming filename as (A1.out, A2.out, A3.out...A18.out).

```
Folder = 'D:\My_Files\';
numberOfFiles=18;
A=zeros(5520,9,numberOfFiles);
for i=1:numberOfFiles
    fileLocation=strcat(Folder,'A',num2str(i),'.out');
    An=load(fileLocation);
    A(:,:,i)=An;
end
```

`A` is the 3D matrix with dimensions (5520x9x18)

**Updated:** For filenames (AA01,AA02,......AA18) and each file has three fields `data`(5520x9),`colheaders`(1x9) and `textdata`(1x9) [got from sample data in the comments]

```
Folder = 'D:\My_Files\';
numberOfFiles=18;
A=zeros(5520,9,numberOfFiles);
for i=1:numberOfFiles
    if (i<10)
        fileLocation=strcat(Folder,'AA0',num2str(i));
    else
        fileLocation=strcat(Folder,'AA',num2str(i));
    end
    An=importdata(fileLocation);
    A(:,:,i)=An.data;
end
```

`A` is the 3D matrix with dimensions (5520x9x18)

Comment: . Thank you. I got error. Conversion to double from struct is not possible.
Error in Data_Read (line 9)
    A(:,:,i)=An;

Comment: It is because the matrix with size 50000x200 is inside that struct or the file contains multiple variables. After running you will get an error, After that got to the workspace and open `An` and it will open in variable editor. Take a screen shot of the variable editor and edit the question above and include the image also.

Comment: In normal case this would have worked. Since its not,without knowing what is in that `An` I wont be able to help. Is there multiple structs inside it or is the required matrix inside it. Guessing wont work.

Comment: What is inside `An` ? I need the variable names and also its dimensions. Open it and tell me or put a screen shot.

Comment: @ Rijul. Thank you so much. Please, first line of my files has text. this is sample of my data.https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rmifu3mik7o8pxp/AADpYR8jkjkP8XxKVyz_AFiBa?dl=0

Comment: @ Rijul. Thank you so much. please, I got an error when I run. Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in not_work (line 13)
    A(:,:,i)=An.data;

Comment: Updated the code. It was a typo. I didn't notice it. Put 5220 instead of 5520.

Comment: @ Rijul. I do not have enough words to thank you. it was a very helpful answer.